# Windows screensaver from HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, screensaver

I've an html page without any external includes with some inline CSS3 animations and JS timers.

Is it possible to convert a simple html file to a screensaver file, which can be further used as a screensaver on my windows and mac desktops?

I mean a real screensaver, which boots once desktop goes to a sleep mode, not the one that  works in the browser.

I know there're some tools available to export swf as a screensaver file, are there any tools available for exporting the HTML? At least, for Windows 8.

Any ideas are respected.

Comment: You might be looking for something like **[This](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/djmclean/htmlscreensaver.html)**? link: http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/djmclean/htmlscreensaver.html

Comment: maybe... have you tried it? looks like it opens ie in a fullscreen mode when a screen saver opens?

Comment: I have not tried it myself but I have seen it running on a computer before. It should work just like a normal screensaver but with a few extra 'goodies'. For me it looks like it takes anything that works on IE.

Comment: I found this http://www.web-screen-saver.com/home.html Searching a bit on google

Comment: We are developing a product to do exactly this, called Screensaver Ninja (https://screensaver.ninja). You might want to check it out.